# Creating App Update Virtual Testing Environment

Tags: iphone, ipad, testing, app-store, updates

I would like to know that,is it possible to create an **App update "Virtual Testing" Environment** .

**Note that any of my application versions are not submitted to App-store yet**.

I am sure that  When a user downloads an application update through iTunes , it installs the update in a new application directory. It then moves the user’s data files from the old installation over to the new application directory before deleting the old installation. Files in the Documents & Library directories are guaranteed to be preserved during the update process.

So I would like to do a test case for my application to verify that above mentioned things regarding to the app update will work fine.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, updates do not install a version in a new directory, just the app gets replaced. The Document, library and such are not moved.

The way you could test an update is, install the old version (either appstore or adhoc) and just install the new versie (either ad-hoc or run in xcode on the device).

Since the apps have the same bundleID the old is replaced with the new one.